# Random sampling from the intersection of cube and simplex

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, sampling, simplex

I'm trying to find a way to randomly sample points from the intersection of the simplex $\Delta_k$, defined by
\begin{equation}
\Delta_k : \{x_i\in\mathbb{R}^n\ |\ 0\leq x_i\leq k, \ x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n = k\}
\end{equation}
with $0\leq k \leq n$ and the unit cube defined by
\begin{equation}
\{x_i\in\mathbb{R}^n\ |\ 0\leq x_i \leq 1\ \}
\end{equation}
Now, I know how to obtain a uniform random sample on the simplex (e.g. from here https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/uniform-sampling-from-a-simplex) and the sampling is trivial on the cube, but how to tackle the intersection?

The intersection in some cases (i.e. for some values of $k$) is another simplex so the problem in those cases is solved, but for instance in the case $n=3$ and for some values of $k$ the intersection is a hexagon.

Comment: Can you sample on the simplex and then throw out the result if it doesn't fall within the cube?  Or is that impractical for the values of $n, k$ you're interested in?

Comment: I could sample from the simplex but the ratio between the measure of the simplex and the intersection goes to zero for $k\rightarrow 0$ or $n$ so in those cases there would be a lot of trials to do before getting a sample on the spot

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/160050/755